# Why is Informix showing numeric errors?

Tags: .net, informix

In a Windows 7 64 bit development machine, a .NET application is getting numeric error messages from Informix.

The very same application xcopied to other machines shows the correct error message strings.

My guess is that I'm missing some PATH, or something like that which is not automatically configured by the installer (clientsdk.3.50.FC7)

<sub>(sidenote: I'm posting here and not in stackoverflow because it looks like an Informix setup issue, even though I'm talking about a dev machine)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you only getting the informix error number like -954 it seems that the error message files were not available (installed) or the env variable %INFORMIXDIR%\msg isn't set.

Comment: @unicard-ic: it wasn't set and I've set it to `c:\Program Files\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK`. But it made no difference. BTW, the server where this usually runs does not have INFORMIXDIR set, yet it displays the messages correctly. Anything else to check? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message file is part of the Informixserver installation, you can copy the path.
Probably then it works.